# Prolog symmetric encryption

Tags: prolog

So i am new to prolog. I need to create a predicate `xor(+Text,+Key,-Cipher).` I can assume that `+Text` and `+Key` have the same length. `+Text` contains a list of 0's and 1's, and so does `+Key`. I need to perform the XOR operator on each element of the list `+Text` and `+Key` and write the output to the `-Cipher` list.

```
xor(+Plaintext,+Key,-Cipher) :-
 / ** TODO **/

xor_check(0,0,0).
xor_check(0,1,1).
xor_check(1,0,1).
xor_check(1,1,0).
```

I made a xor_check for all the possible outcomes but am not sure how to pass the elements of my list to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily process [lists](https://boklm.eu/prolog/page_7.html) in Prolog using [recursion](https://boklm.eu/prolog/page_6.html).

As you assume that Plaintext and Key have the same length, you can process it as follows:

```
xor([], [], []).
xor([P|Plaintext], [K|Key], [C|Cipher]) :-
    xor_check(P, K, C),
    xor(Plaintext, Key, Cipher).
```